# Conditional rendering of components in a react-native custom button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am an old programmer learning to use react-native.

I'm having trouble as I seem unable to effectively utilise conditional rendering of components. My goal here is to load this button conditionally.

This is a strange problem and I have spent the entire day trying to solve it, I am using the renderIf technique in one of the application's scenes and **it is working perfectly**. However, when I use it in this component it immediately crashes, 
throwing an NSException.

I have used the terminal command **npm install render-if --save** to install the package which worked perfectly for the scene but not for this component.

Any help would be hugely appreciated and any suggestions on alternative methods would also be appreciated.

***GeneralButton.js***

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

import renderIf from 'render-if';

class GeneralButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      render: true
    }
  }

  getWidth(){
    let width, percent;
    if (this.props.percent == true) {
      let screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
      width = (screenWidth / 100) * this.props.width;
      return width;
    } else {
      percent = false;
      width = this.props.width != null ? this.props.width : 300;
      return width;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {renderIf(this.state.render)(
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)' onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <View style={styles.button} width={this.getWidth()}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              {this.props.text}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )}
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    height: 44,
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Light',
      },
      android: {
        fontFamily: 'opensanslight',
      },
    })
  },
});

module.exports = GeneralButton;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, component renders function returns a component instance. Wrap your render content in `View`. In your case there is no need to use `renderIf`, you can use inline if:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.state.render &&
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)' onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <View style={styles.button} width={this.getWidth()}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              {this.props.text}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      }
    </View>
  )
}
```